# How do I iterate over a Dictionary<string, StringValues> collection obtained from QueryHelpers.ParseQuery?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-5

When I call

```
QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);
```

it returns

```
Dictionary<string, StringValues>
```

When I view this collection in the Visual Studio "Locals" window, I see something like this:

```
Count = 4

{[q, {qOne, qTwo}]}
"q"
{qOne, qTwo}

{[selection, {sOne, sTwo}]}
"selection"
{sOne, sTwo}

{[color, {cOne, cTWo}]}
"color"
{cOne, cTwo}

{[option, {oOne, oTwo}]}
"option"
{oOne, oTwo}
```

If I look at the Microsoft **[documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.primitives.stringvalues?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0)** for `StringValues` it says:

```
GetEnumerator() - Retrieves an object that can iterate through the individual strings in this StringValues.
```

That tells me that I should be able to do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, StringValues> queryString = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);

foreach(string key in queryString.Keys){
    Console.WriteLine("KEY: " + key);
    foreach(string value in queryString.Value[key].GetEnumerator()){
        Console.WriteLine("VALUE: " + value);
    }
}
```

But there isn't any option for that `queryString.Value[key]` that I need to do this.

So, how do I iterate over this particular `Dictionary<string, StringValues>` collection?

Comment: Try it without `.GetEnumerator()`, just `foreach(string value in queryString.Value[key])`.

Comment: Remove `.GetEnumerator()` to enumerate the strings

Comment: You are spelling `queryString[s]` two different ways, is this just a typo?

Comment: @RBarryYoung Yes, a typo. My apologies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, StringValues> queryStrings = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);

foreach(var stringValues in queryString.Values){
foreach(var value in stringValues)
Console.WriteLine("VALUE: " + value);
}
```

If you need the keys:

```
Dictionary<string, StringValues> queryStrings = QueryHelpers.ParseQuery(uri.Query);

foreach(var key in queryString.Keys){
    Console.WriteLine("KEY: " + key);
    foreach(var value in queryString[key]){
        Console.WriteLine("VALUE: " + value);
    }
}
```

Comment: I did, indeed, need the keys as well. Fantastic, thank you ... I was getting very lost.